# How can I access JSON elements received from an external source using jQuery getJSON()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to read JSON information (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Mountain+View+Amphitheatre+Parkway&sensor=false) from JavaScript using:

```
$.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+city+"+"+steet+"&sensor=false", function(json) {
if (json.status == 'ZERO_RESULTS'){
    alert('Wrong input');
}
else{
// Here I would like to read json.results.geometry.location.lat 
}

});
```

But it does not work. If I try to read json.results, I get [object Object]. Because printing json gave me the same I thought I could just continue with periods, but it did not work.

After that I tried to iterate over json.results and after to parse the object to an array, but all did not work.

Comment: What did you **actually** do when you say "If I try to read json.results". I'm guessing you tried to `alert()` it? If that is the case, don't; `alert()` isn't suitable for debugging, use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/RmbTD/1/

Answer (score 2):

results is an array of objects. So you should try:

```
json.results[0].geometry.location.lat
```

Answer (score 1):

`json.results` is an Array, you have to access the Elements inside it.

The code you have, as is, is trying to access the property `location` of the object `geometry`.

But since `json.results` is an Array, `json.results.geometry` is `undefined` and therefore cannot have a property.

If you would check the Errors in the console, you should get something like

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`

What you want is accessing the Elements of the `results` Array, as each Element in it represents one search result of gMaps, which then holds the information you want to access.

e.g. `json.results[0]` would give you the Object representing the first search result,
`json.results[1]` would give you the second, and so on.

So if you change it to

```
$.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Berlin+Alexanderplatz&sensor=false", function(json) {
if (json.status == 'ZERO_RESULTS'){
    alert('Wrong input');
}
else{
  console.log(json.results[0].geometry.location.lat) // 52.5218316
}

});
```

You get the Latitude of the first result, just as you intended to.

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/axesit/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

results is an array where you should loop over:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.results.length; i++) {
     console.log(json.results[i].geometry.location.lat);
}
```